# Rails and using Gulp/Grunt to inject code to views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, assets

How would I use one of the Gulp/Grunt plugins that compile some type of asset and then replace a custom comment line in a view with either a set of script or link tags etc in Rails so that the view file is not seen as changed everytime that happens by my version control system?

Comment: Why would gulp or grunt need to re-write your view files? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: For example: This module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject  This replaces a special comment tag with links to compiled assets.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clumsy way to do asset fingerprinting compared to how its [done by sprockets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark). You probably could setup a build system to perform in in a post-commit hook - but why bother? Sprockets just works and does the job well enough - unlike Gulp which always goes tits up every time the weather changes.

Comment: I have a custom built gulp based system that's been working perfectly and does a lot more that's a lot more customised to my particular app.

Comment: Are you currently creating a dist or build package separate from your version controlled directory?